# Firebase Cloud Message difference between send to Tokens and Notificartion keys

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I know the HTTP v1 APIs are not support device group managment, And I am consider using only HTTP v1 APIs for reduce project complexity.

As far as I know from github [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/173#issuecomment-418834805):

> Send to all tokens instead of device group will work for a small
> number of device tokens. But it won't scale for large groups

But I don't know what is the limitation of send to mutiple tokens and Notificartion keys?